# how to set up a random sequence to perform certain groups of lines in python?

Tags: python, random

I have a list of questions, each question requires user input, for example:

```
two = '\N{subscript two}'
three = '\N{subscript three}'
four = '\N{subscript four}'
seven = '\N{subscript seven}'
#first_question
PO_4 = "PO{}".format(four)
quantity = int(input("what's the valence of %s?" % PO_4))
while quantity != -3:
    quantity = int(input("wrong answer, please try again"))
name = input("what's the chemical name of {}?".format(PO_4))
while name != "phosphate":
    name = input("wrong answer, please try again")

#-2
SO_4 = "SO{}".format(four)
quantity = int(input("what's the valence of %s?" % SO_4))
while quantity != -2:
    quantity = int(input("wrong answer, please try again"))
name = input("what's the chemical name of {}?".format(SO_4))
while name != "sulphate":
    name = input("wrong answer, please try again")
```

Currently each question contains a while loop.

I want the students to give a correct answer to the questions and I want the questions to be asked at random, after they have answered each question once, then I'd like the program to terminate.

I have read about random, however, all of the answers are about statistics.

Could you please offer me some help? I want the questions to be asked at 
random. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please post the actual text of your code instead of a picture of it.

Comment: Take a look at the `random` module, especially its `choice` and `shuffle` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example I have modified to work with Python 3, added the removal once a question has been asked and added a score (assumption).

```
import random

correctAnswers = 0
incorrectAnswers = 0

capitals = {'Alabama':'Montgomery', 'Alaska':'Juneau', 'Arizona':'Phoenix'}
states = list(capitals.keys())

random.shuffle(states)
for state in states:
    answer = input("Capital of %s? " % state)
    if answer == capitals[state]:
        print ('Correct!')
        correctAnswers += 1
        del capitals[state]
    else:
        print ('Wrong!')
        incorrectAnswers += 1
        del capitals[state]

print("Correct Answers %s " % correctAnswers)
print("Incorrect Answers %s " % incorrectAnswers)
```